# how to change the state of a <input type="file"> or unload the file , after file is chosen to "No file chosen" using a button

Tags: jquery, html

I use ajax to save a file, but I want to unload or change the state of  to no file chosen, in other words, I want to Unmount, unload the image after my operation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$("input[type='file']").val("");
```

For example

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("input[type='file']").val("");
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file">
<button>reset</button>
```